# Deploying two ASP.NET MVC projects to Azure on the same root domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, azure

We would like to deploy two ASP.NET MVC projects to Azure. They way we want the URL structure to work is that when users browse to www.sitename.com/app1 it will reach the first application, and when they browse to www.sitename.com/app2 it will reach the second application.

If it was IIS we could configure it, but even though we have remote access to the Azure machine, we cannot assume it'll be the same machine tomorrow (due to how Azure works).

We don't want to merge the two applications, but keep them separate.

Is it possible at all? What's the best practice?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking to use Virtual applications?

In which case, you can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg433110.aspx:

> **Partitioning a domain by using virtual
>   applications**
>
> When you create a web role, you create
>   a cloud project with one web role that
>   is configured as a web site. The
>   following procedure explains how to
>   add a virtual application to the web
>   role.
>
> **To configure the additional site in
>   the cloud project**
>
> Open the ServiceDefinition.csdef for
>   the cloud service.
>
> Under the Sites element for the
>   WebRole, copy the following XML code.
>
> ```
> <Site name="web-site-name">   
> <VirtualApplication name="web-application-name" physicalDirectory=”directory-path" />
> <Bindings>
>    <Binding name="binding-name" endpointName="endpoint-identifier" />   
> </Bindings>
> ```

For a full walkthrough, try: http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/